# workflow_run was not triigered in github actions

Tags: github-actions

I have 2 workflows

first one looks as following

```
name: "Terraform Staging Destroy"

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - staging
  pull_request:
    types:
        - closed
    branches:
      - staging

jobs:
  terraform:
    name: "Terraform Staging Destroy"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions: write-all
    steps:
      - name: test by AAAA
        run: echo "Hello World"
      - name: Sleep for 120 seconds
        run: sleep 120
```

second one will be triggered by first one, the code looks like as following

```
name: "Terraform Staging Apply"

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["Terraform Staging Destroy"]
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  terraform:
    name: "Terraform Staging Apply"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions: write-all
    steps:
      - name: test by BBBBB
        run: echo "Awesome BBBB"
```

When I ran them, there is no any syntax error, but second workflow was not triggered at all when first one.

I expect, first workflow will be done 2 minutes (since it sleep 2 minutes), then once it is done, it will send an event to second workflow, second workflow will be run. But it doesn't work like this, second workflow was not triggered by first workflow.

Any ideas how to trigger second workflow?

Comment: Is your second workflow (`workflow_run`) on the default branch?

Comment: I don't see it in the default branch

Comment: According to [`workflow_call`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run) event, "**Note: This event will only trigger a workflow run if the workflow file is on the default branch.**".